# Quickblox webrtc video call not connected or not recieved

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, quickblox

I am working with quickblox webrtc video calling process. I am stuck on when some one recive my call and I am not getting response when the user accept my call this is the method.

This method not call and I am not getting that he pick my call.

```
-(void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session userDoesNotRespond:(NSNumber *)userID {

    if (session == self.session) {

        [self performUpdateUserID:userID block:^(OpponentCollectionViewCell *cell) {
            cell.connectionState = [self.session connectionStateForUser:userID];
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @VIVEK, did you found the solution, I am implementing Quickblox in iOS, in my case userDoesNotRespond method is not called, I have set the delegate [[QBRTCClient instance] addDelegate:self]  in viewDidLoad method of the View controller.